# Node HTTP Timeout When Sending Cookies in Header (Request/Restler)

Tags: php, node.js, rest, cookies

I'm working on a RESTFUL api using Node. Here is what should be happening:

1. Web page sends REST request to node server over SSL (This request includes a cookie: ci_session that we will use to authenticate)
2. Node server looks up permission code for requested action (Each resource has it's own code)
3. Sends a RESTful request to PHP server to authenticate using the cookie from step 1 and the permission code from step 2.
4. PHP server responds with a success/fail
5. If success is returned, then have node execute the requested resource
6. Page from step 1 gets response

My problem is at step #3.

```
//Using 'Restler'(which is built on 'Request')
var rest = require("restler");

//Authenticate
//This is Hanging
rest.get( 'URL_TO_PHP_REST', {    headers:{
                                      "Cookie": v_cookie
                                  }
                              }
).on("success", function(){...});
```

**Debugging:**

- I've tested all of my RESTful end points with Postman; they work.
- If I omit the cookie from step #3, then the request goes through instantly *(though the user will always fail the auth check)*
- Cookies and URL are their expected values

**Sample Cookie**:

`ac=0atu2rrp5ifeet0s5kdb62rbeov7ktnr`

**How Restler Sends Requests**

```
//Parameters
//url = 'URL_TO_PHP_REST'
//options = {headers:{"Cookie":"ac=0atu2rrp5ifeet0s5kdb62rbeov7ktnr"}}

var request = new Request(url, options);
request.on('error', function() {});
process.nextTick(request.run.bind(request));
return request;
```

Comment: What is the exact Postman command line that works?

Comment: I solved the problem (see below). But thank you for offering your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out The problem was not with my REST server but with my PHP server. The same PHP server was both requesting data from Node.js and authenticating the request. However, PHP cannot process the same session in parallel.

Solutions:

- Adding session_write_close() in the requesting script clears the lock so authentication can run.
- Request resources using a different server/language (ie. Use node front-end instead of PHP)